# Can I use Jyn Odan's Quick Draw if I don't have line of sight normally, but do with Trick Shot?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

Jyn Odan's Quick Draw works as follows:

> 2 Strain: Use at the start of a hostile figure's activation. Interrupt to perform an attack with a Pistol targeting that figure. Limit once per round (twice if you have 2 activation tokens).

For 4 XP, Jyn can buy the Trick Shot skill:

> 1 Strain: Use before you declare an attack with a Ranged weapon. You can draw line of sight from any space within 3 spaces.

It's not clear to me: can these two can be used together? Can I use Quick Draw against someone I don't normally have line of sight to, but do with Trick Shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

Justin Kemppainen, Assistant Board Game Manager for Fantasy Flight Games, [definitively stated that it is allowed](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/137140-jyn-odan-trick-shot-counting-spaces-and-quick-draw/?p=1497618):

> Question:
>   If a Trooper "just around the corner" (out of LOS) activates, can Jyn activate Quick Draw and Trick Shot (to gain LOS) to attack him?
>
> Answer:
>   Yep! That combination of abilities is legit, and they remain legit even if the target is not currently in line of sight.